# requirejs loading the modules

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I have a JS file ClaimStartup.main.js.

```
(function ($, window,require) {
window.claimStartup = function (options) {                
    this.factoryInstance = null;
}
claimStartup.prototype = {
    init: function (params) {
         var self = this;
        require(['ClaimStartupFactory'],
            function(ClaimStartupFactory) {
                self.factoryInstance = ClaimStartupFactory(claimTypeCode);
            });            
        return self;
    }
```

ClaimStartupFactory is defined in a different JS file (ClaimStartupFactory.js)

```
define(function (require) {
var claimTypes = {
    'JAL': require('JALModule')
    , 'SeniorCare': require('SeniorCareModule')
    //, 'W2': require('modules/W2')
};
return function (claimType) {
    try {
        return new claimTypes[claimType];
    } catch (error) {
        throw new Error('Unknown Claim Type Specified.');
    }
}
});
```

When i debug this I am getting error

```
Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function () {
 return {
    // declare the function to change the background color
    setBackgroundJAL: function (color) {
        console.log('HI');
    }
};

}
```

JAL.module.js is:

```
define(function () {
   return {
    // declare the function to change the background color
    setBackgroundJAL: function (color) {
        console.log('HI');
    }
};
});
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong with the usage?
This is MVC5.net application, maybe I am missing .net bundling with requireJS configuration.
Do i require requirejs config file for my scenario?

Thanks
Sajesh

Answer (score 0):

You have two `require` calls of the form `require(moduleName)` where `moduleName` is a string. That's the CommonJS form of the `require` call. RequireJS is an AMD module loader, it does not do CommonJS *as-is*. It does provide some facilities to ease the transition from CommonJS to AMD. So it will allow the CommonJS form of calling `require` but only if this `require` call is *a local `require` inside a `define` call*.

A *local* `require` is one that is obtained through the dependencies provided by the `define` call. That's by opposition to the *global* require which exists in the global space. You cannot use the global `require` for making CommonJS-style `require` calls.

In your `ClaimStartup.main.js`, you are using the global `require` to make a `require` call in the CommonJS style. That's not allowed and you get the error you get. You need either:

- Use an AMD-style `require` call, which means passing an array of dependencies an providing a callback: `require(['ClaimStartupFactory'], function (factory) {`. Note that this `require` is asynchronous so you have to take that into account.
- Make that file into a proper AMD module. Wrap it in a `define(function (require) {` so that it gets a local `require` that you  can call.

---

Your `ClaimStartupFactory.js` file is also problematic because it mixes AMD style and CommonJS style. You should either pass all your dependencies to the array given to `define`:

```
define(['modules/JALModule'], function (JAL) {
var claimTypes = {
  'JAL': JAL
```

or use only CommonJS-style `require` calls:

```
define(function (require) {
var claimTypes = {
  'JAL': require('modules/JALModule')
```

I've removed `'ClaimStartupFactory'` from the list in both cases because that dependency was bizarre: it looked like your module was dependent on itself.

---

If you want to learn the mechanics of all it wall works behind the scenes, I have another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42179544/1906307) that deals with that.

Comment: Thanks Louis for your suggestion..I made the changes as you suggested but I am seeing a different error now, not sure what is wrong now

Comment: Appreciate your inputs on this for me to proceed